# Observable array or in memory collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to create an observable array or in memory collection in Meteor?

The way I'm faking it is by creating a session variable containing the array, `Session.setDefault('people', [])`; and then updating that value when the array changes, `Session.set('people', modifiedArray)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a local collection by calling `Meteor.Collection` constructor without supplying collection name in the parameter, i.e.:

```
LocalList = new Meteor.Collection();
```

See this in [the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection).

Notice also that you can observe anything you want thanks to [Dependencies](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency).

Example:

```
List = function() {
    this.data = [];
    this.dep = new Deps.Dependency();
};

_.extends(List.prototype, {
    insert: function(element) {
        this.data.push(element);
        this.dep.changed();
    },
});

var list = new List();

Template.observer.helper = function() {
    list.dep.depend();
    return list.data;
};
```

`helper` will be updated and `observer` template will rerender each time you call `list.insert` function.

Comment: Since 0.9.1, Meteor.Collection() has become Mongo.Collection()