# How to tell meteor to "watch" for changes in an array?

Tags: meteor

I have something like this:

```
<template name ="products">
    <br />
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        {{#each products.items}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{price}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td><td>{{products.totalPrice}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>


Template.products.helpers({
        products: function () {
            try {
                var user = Session.get("user");
                return JSON.parse(localStorage[user]); //this return*
            } catch (e) {

            } 
        }
    });
```

*this returns something like this `{totalPrice: 30, items:[{"productId1","name1","10"},{"productId2","name2","20"}]}`

The question is: I need to have this info stored in localStorage and not in a Meteor.Collection as i dont want to go to the server until moment X (Doesn't matter really). But I cant make this thing auto update whenever I change localStorage value. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you are not using `Meteor.Collection( null )` to create a local collection?

Comment: Where does meteor store that local collection? Thanks a lot

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Observable array or in memory collection in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278980/observable-array-or-in-memory-collection-in-meteor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [Dependencies](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps) are for. Simplest example:

```
var array = [];
var arrayDep = new Deps.Dependency();

Template.name.helper = function() {
    arrayDep.depend();
    return array;
};

var change = function() {
    // do things to Array contents
    arrayDep.changed();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in some hours!

Answer (score 1):

Store the info in the `Session` as it is reactive so your template will change every time the value in the Session changes.

You could also use the [browser-store](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-browser-store) package that seems to make localstorage reactive.